# PIG join is resulting in zero rows. empty results

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here is the dump of table description :

```
A = LOAD '/tmp/all.csv' as (cmd:chararray,q1:int,q2:int,q3:int);
R = LOAD '/tmp/raw.csv' as (cmd:chararray,duration:int);
A: {cmd: chararray,q1: int,q2: int,q3: int}
R: {cmd: chararray,duration: int}
J: {A::cmd: chararray,A::q1: int,A::q2: int,A::q3: int,R::cmd: chararray,R::duration: int}
```

Here are the A and R Tables :

```
=== A ==-=
A,5,10,20
B,25,50,75
=== R ===
A,6
A,12
A,22
B,30
B,55
B,80
```

I do join by following command :

```
J = join A BY cmd, R BY cmd;
```

This seems pretty straight forward, but when I dump the table J, it always return  empty/null.

```
DUMP J;
Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in
```

Any idea what I may be missing ?

Comment: show all of your code, please.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question. Can you add details such as what Storage classes you're using.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought those are the only command that are relevent.
Dump of the original files, join and dump of join.
Which other command you want me to post ?

Comment: How do you load the data to A and R?

Comment: You are wrong @Ajeet. All of the code is relevant. Everything you posted makes sense, so something is missing. I'm going to guess you are loading the data wrong or transforming it in some way.

Comment: I bet you are loading the data with PigStorage and not specifying comma as a delimiter. Tab is the default. So it is printing fine, but everything is jammed into the first column. That's my guess.

Comment: Try `C = FOREACH A GENERATE cmd; DUMP cmd` And the same for R respectively. Does it print the As and Bs only?

Comment: @DonaldMiner : YOu are correct. It was that issue. Just put your comment as answer and I will accept it. :)  Thank you.